# Catch all request expect areas .NET 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-5

We started as a .net (5) core mvc project for a new project.

One of our two important directions is the part for Areas

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "AdminArea",
                pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Dashboard}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

The other part is I want to drop all requests into a single controller.

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                   name: "default",
                   pattern: "{controller=AllRequest}/{action=Index}");
```

I add the tag below to capture requests in the controller

```
public class AllRequestController : Controller
    {
        [Route("{*queryvalues}")]
        public IActionResult Index()
```

But when I make this addition, I lose areas, how can I leave this part in the requests coming there

Comment: Leave the routes as they are but call a common method like Index() for all the routes. You can add a parameter like Index(string route) so you can distinguish between routes.

Comment: Sorry I can't imagine it in my head. Do you have a chance to show a tiny example? Can a blog link be?

Comment: You cannot omit the area value in url. If you specify that in url, it should work correctly. Can you show the example requests to areas(url paths) that fails.

Comment: When I add the route tag above to the controller eg. The link example.com/admin takes me allrequest index action. But if I remove that tag, everything works correctly. What I want is the same controller and action drops, except for the links under admin.

Comment: Make sure the area is mapped first and has higher priority

Comment: yes so i changed their order etc but there was not much difference.